# How to submit a form with an iframe that contains an input inside without using Window.postMessage() to support old browsers

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, submit

- There is a form.
- Inside the form, there is an iframe and a submit button.
- The iframe points to a different domain and inside the iframe, there is an text box input.

Expectation: click submit button to POST the value in the textbox input inside the iframe to server.

Note that, as iframe and page are from different domains, we can't use js to get the value of the text box. And we can't use Window.postMessage() as described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage in order to support old browsers.

Any solution?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.postMessage

Comment: we can't use Window.postMessage() as described in https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage in order to support old browsers.